# How do I correctly reinitialize a loop variable in C?

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

I was wondering where the error logic in my code was, I suspect that it lies in the failure of my loop to run through completely before printing the prime numbers, but I cannot seem to fix it. I have tried reinitializing the variable fcount to 0 each time, but the resulting "prime numbers" is incorrect. My goal for the program is to have a user input number N that I can loop from 1 to N and print all prime numbers inbetween. I would highly appreciate if someone could help point out the error in my logic, and any possible solutions, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,j,n, fcount = 0;
    printf("Enter number n:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("prime numbers are:\n");
    for (i=1; i < n; i++)
        {
          for (j = i; j > 0; j--)
              {

                if (i%j == 0)
                    {
                      fcount++;     
                      // at some point every number will have fcount =2
                      fcount = 0;
                    }

              }

        }

         if (fcount == 2)
            {
                printf("%d\n",i);
            } 
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: To reinitialize `fcount`, set it to zero at the point in the code where you want it set to zero—just after getting a new value of `i` and just before starting to count values of `j` that are factors of `i`. Then, to test whether a number `i` has two factors, test `fcount` after you have finished counting the factors and before you move on to a new value of `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a very efficient way to test for primes, but the method works. You have two errors, though:

- For each `i`, the `fcount` must start at 0, so `fcount = 0` should be the first thing in that loop.
- You must test `fcount == 2` for each `i`, not just once at the end, so move that test into the loop over `i`.

Some observations about your code:

- These errors could have been spotted easier if you had formatted the code properly: Plese make a habit of indenting every block in curly braces so that the code's structure becomes clear.
- It is better to declare the variables where they are needed. That means that `fcount` can be local to the loop over `i`. The loop variable `i` and `j` can directly be declared in the loop header.

Putting all this together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter number n:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    // Should test for input errors ...

    printf("prime numbers are:\n");

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int fcount = 0;

        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                fcount++;
            }
        }

        if (fcount == 2) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```